# JSSOR - Is it possible to fade in/out bullets/thumbnails when sliding?

Tags: jssor

Like the title says is it possible to fade out bullets or thumbnails when starting to slide and fade in when its stopping with the slide animation? I looked into the development section but can't seem to find anything about it.

At the moment I just always show the thumbnails but it looks weird when the sliding animation is running. It would be great if there's a way to do this without to much custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have a bullet navigator element as follows,

```
<div u="navigator" class="jssorb03" ...>
...
</div>
```

You can make it fade out while swipe start, and fade in while swipe end.

```
function SwipeStartEventHandler(position) {
    if(Math.floor(position) == position)
        $(".jssorb03").fadeOut();
}

function SwipeEndEventHandler(position) {
    if(Math.floor(position) == position)
        $(".jssorb03").fadeIn();
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SWIPE_START, SwipeStartEventHandler);
jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SWIPE_END, SwipeEndEventHandler);
```

Comment: Works like a charm except when I manually drag the slider it seems like its executing the event twice.

Comment: You can check if the `position` parameter is an integer. See updated answer.